# Reducing Build time for Kentico Web application

Tags: msbuild, kentico

I have a Kentico 8.1 web application, which is taking me 25 minutes to build. I am doing some custom development on this application.

I like to know incrementally, how is it possible to build so that the strongly type objects are available in the code behind ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using *Web Application Project*?

Kentico 8.1 *Web Application Project* takes **less than a minute** to build.

However Kentico 8.1 *Web Site Project* takes **about 30 minutes** to build, which is probably your case.

Compare [differences between Web Application Projects and Web Site Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) and consider changing your project type.

Comment: How do I change my project type from Web Site Project to Web Application Project. I have already build the project.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but I would also point out that with web site projects you don't **need** to build them.

- If you're adding code into App_Code, the website wont run.
- If you're adding Web Parts, you're probably testing them as you go.
- If you have a large amount of code that does warrant compiling/testing/whatever, you can put that code into a separate class library and compile that.